# Greek font display error in Flutter with Exo

Tags: flutter, fonts

I want to display a certain text in my app in Greek. But it seems that certain characters don't work in Flutter (the vertical letter looking symbol). I use the Font Exo from Google fonts and I tried this font already in a web application and in my Webapp the Greek text is displayed without any problem, which means that the font definitely supports all the Greek letters.

[image]

In the pubspec.yaml I put the font in the following way:

```
  fonts:
    - family: Exo
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/exo/Exo-Thin.ttf
          weight: 100
        - asset: assets/fonts/exo/Exo-ThinItalic.ttf
          weight: 100
          style: italic
        - asset: assets/fonts/exo/Exo-ExtraLight.ttf
          weight: 200
        - asset: assets/fonts/exo/Exo-ExtraLightItalic.ttf
          weight: 200
          style: italic
        - asset: assets/fonts/exo/Exo-Light.ttf
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/fonts/exo/Exo-LightItalic.ttf
          weight: 300
          style: italic
        - asset: assets/fonts/exo/Exo-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/exo/Exo-Italic.ttf
          weight: 400
          style: italic
        - asset: assets/fonts/exo/Exo-Medium.ttf
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/exo/Exo-MediumItalic.ttf
          weight: 500
          style: italic
        - asset: assets/fonts/exo/Exo-SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/exo/Exo-SemiBoldItalic.ttf
          weight: 600
          style: italic
        - asset: assets/fonts/exo/Exo-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/exo/Exo-BoldItalic.ttf
          weight: 700
          style: italic
        - asset: assets/fonts/exo/Exo-ExtraBold.ttf
          weight: 800
        - asset: assets/fonts/exo/Exo-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf
          weight: 800
          style: italic
        - asset: assets/fonts/exo/Exo-Black.ttf
          weight: 900
        - asset: assets/fonts/exo/Exo-BlackItalic.ttf
          weight: 900
          style: italic
```

And the files are also properly saved in my app:

[image]

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? How can I implement the font properly that also the Greek language works properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your application on mobile, deinstall and reinstall the app from the device. This is necessary so that flutter can load all the files referenced in `pubspec.yaml`.

Comment: Hi jraufeisen, unfortunatly this solution didn't work. I figured out that when I delete all the fonts: - part and leave only  ```fonts: - family: Exo``` part it works but then I don't have bold and italic support anymore... But I dont' really know what to do with this knowledge know...